# JQuery ajax is not recognized with request.is_ajax() in Django using Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery to send an ajax request for Django. To select the response template I'm checking the request like this:

```
def about(request) :
    context = {'content' : 'about.html',
               'section_nav' : 'about_nav.html'}

    if request.is_ajax() :
        context['ajax'] = True

    return render_to_response('main.html', context)
```

In main.html I check either if is ajax or not and extend a different template.
And the jQuery is simple as:

```
$.get('/about/', function(data) {
        $('.article').html(data);
});
```

In Chrome and Firefox it works just fine... but IE9 returns False in request.is_ajax() and loads the page with the wrong context.
How can I overcome this problem, and make an ajax request from IE (with jQuery) and recognize it with django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$.ajax` instead of `$.get`. I've read that using `$.ajax` works with all browsers but `$.get` won't send the ajax header with IE.

Also set the cache option to false.

Comment: Problem solved. Get still works, the problem was with the cache parameter. Do you know why this happens @themanatuf?

Answer (score 0):

When making a jQuery ajax request, I've found at least one version of IE that does not send the appropriate header for django's request method is_ajax() to work -- the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header with the string 'XMLHttpRequest'

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax

To fix this, add the header manually in the jQuery $.ajax call, ie, $.ajax({'headers': {'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'},...});